# geth javascript console: web3.eth.subscribe ==> "Object has no member 'subscribe'"

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I must be missing something -- I am trying to use the web3.eth.subscribe() function in my geth node's javascript console and there is no subscribe function.

```
    Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.9.23-stable-8c2f2715/linux-arm64/go1.15.3
coinbase: 0xc029cea32eb050a35c23e82ad1fecd20087283bc
at block: 7463930 (Sat Oct 31 2020 04:03:00 GMT+0000 (UTC))
 datadir: /home/rinkeby/.ethereum/rinkeby
 modules: admin:1.0 clique:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
```

```
web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions')
TypeError: Object has no member 'subscribe'
        at <eval>:1:19(5)
```

Comment: I'm not really sure but I think geth's console still uses web3 version 0.20 which doesn't have support for subscribe.